# Get several images in telegram bot instead of one

Tags: api, telegram-bot

I am trying to read sended images on telegram bot. But if I even send one image, I get request with 2 or 3 images:

```
{
"update_id": 89590957,
"message": {
    ...
    "photo": [
        {
            "file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAANXXoB34ITIXzlhPNp0P0mldwtVb_AAAoquMRt_4QlIhnmbxJbRlbTrmMIPAAQBAAMCAANtAAM1FQYAARgE",
            "file_unique_id": "AQAD65jCDwAENRUGAAE",
            "file_size": 10772,
            "width": 229,
            "height": 320
        },
        {
            "file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAANXXoB34ITIXzlhPNp0P0mldwtVb_AAAoquMRt_4QlIhnmbxJbRlbTrmMIPAAQBAAMCAAN4AAM2FQYAARgE",
            "file_unique_id": "AQAD65jCDwAENhUGAAE",
            "file_size": 26334,
            "width": 445,
            "height": 621
        }
    ] 
}
```

This request I get via:

```
data = request.data
data["message"]["photo"]
```

How can I understand which image is original? Or may be its possible to receive only one image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is a thumbnail, the second is the full size image.  You can see this from the `file_size` for each item.

To get the `file_id` of the full size image you can access the last item in the list using:

```
data["message"]["photo"][-1].file_id
```

This accounts for the fact that if a larger image is sent, there may be several thumbnails and an original.  Although this is based on my own testing.  I struggled to find any documentation which states this specifically.

Comment: But what if I'll send several images? Are there any simple way or I should check sizes lokking for increasing of it?

Comment: @Maksim it appears that if you send multiple photos they are always treated as separate updates.  [Here's the code](https://pastebin.com/46fKcd2K) I've been using to test this using `python-telegram-bot`.  If you send 2 photos to this bot in a single message, the handler is invoked twice, once for each photo. The bot is set to reply with `len(update.message.photo)` so expect two replies stating the number of images the API has split each photo into; again larger photos will have more sub-images.